# Phonegap Notification not working in phonegap developer android app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap Developer App to test my app during development. But I can't get the plugins to start working. In this case I am using the notification. JavaScript alert works but notification.alert is not working. Please I have been going around this for days now. Here is what my code looks like.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('session') == null){
        navigator.notification.alert("Not logged in", null, "Login?", "Continue");
        navigator.notification.beep(1);
        navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
        //alert('not logged in');
        }else{
            navigator.notification.alert("Logged in", null, "Login?", "Continue");
            navigator.notification.beep(1);
            navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
            //alert('logged in');
            }
</script>
```

Comment: The *PhoneGap Developer App* has nothing to do with *Phonegap Build*. I have removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

@ITECH-PLANET,
if you are using the standard example that comes with the *PhoneGap Developer App*, then you **MUST** wait until the `deviceready` has *fired*.

You can test this by putting function section of code in a function, then calling that function.

Like this:

```
app.notify : function () {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('session') == null){
        navigator.notification.alert("Not logged in", null, "Login?", "Continue");
        navigator.notification.beep(1);
        navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
        //alert('not logged in');
    }else{
        navigator.notification.alert("Logged in", null, "Login?", "Continue");
        navigator.notification.beep(1);
        navigator.notification.vibrate(1000);
        //alert('logged in');
        }
}
```

Then change to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    app.notify();
</script>
```

For additional details read [#4](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#004) of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: I don't know where exactly I am to paste the code. Also does it that anytime I want to call a plugin, I must create a function for that?

Comment: Apparently, you should be learning more about javascript. I'll get you some tutorials. In the meantime, post in on some public website the Javascript that has your `app.initialize()` code.